# Error while installing Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

So I used this command to install notebook:

```
conda install jupyter nb_conda ipykernel
```

But it gives me this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Aryan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_*init*_.py)

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: What does your environment contain? At which step do you get the `ImportError`?

Comment: After it confirms downloading the packages, it gives me the error. And what do you mean what does my environment contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uh, maybe you can get you answer from the github

look at this https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3435

and you can learn more from the google searching